# Codeblocks wont run on new MAC OS Sonoma

Tags: macos, codeblocks, macos-sonoma

I recently updated my mac to Sonoma 14 and now codeblocks 17.2 does not run on my mac M1 chip

Comment: Insufficient information. What is "codeblocks"? What happens when you attempt to run it?

Comment: Codeblocks is an IDE for c++

Comment: gives below error

-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               codeblocks [3298]
Path:                  /Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/codeblocks
Identifier:            codeblocks
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Translated)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2023-10-06 09:36:22.4830 +0200
OS Version:            macOS 14.0 (23A344)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        DBF8BCCA-0D08-D3FA-6085-14D08494AC